How can I unpin directories in ChromeOS?
On ChromeOS, the Files app insists on pinning the directories first.
It is only way down after all the directories are listed that we can
finally see any actual files.
It's just like if in Linux we were sentenced to
$ ls --group-directories-first
for life with no parole.
How can I unpin directories in ChromeOS?

Well you could submit a misfeature unrequest,
and while you are waiting for them to unfix it,
do (Linux example):
$ mkdir d
$ mv dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4... d

Voila, now only one directory pinned. In fact you might even grow to
like it.

Well that is very kind of you to provide such a workaround. However it
only affects one directory.

Yes. I only use it on my Downloads directory, where 99% percent of
the irritation occurs.
